# Why does pointer addition work in NASM, 32 bits programming?

Tags: pointers, assembly, nasm

```
mov ah, a+b
```

where a and b can be found in the data segment, like:

```
a db 0
b db 32
```

This works in NASM, where a and b are pointers (the values in NASM are represented as `[a]` and `[b]`.

Does anyone know why the addition works? And how it works? Could somebody explain it to me? I'm new to NASM and this doesn't make any sense!

Edit:
Here is the code that I'm using

```
bits 32 ; assembling for the 32 bits architecture

; declare the EntryPoint (a label defining the very first instruction of the program)
global start        

; declare external functions needed by our program
extern exit               ; tell nasm that exit exists even if we won't be defining it
import exit msvcrt.dll    ; exit is a function that ends the calling process. It is defined in msvcrt.dll
                          ; msvcrt.dll contains exit, printf and all the other important C-runtime specific functions

; our data is declared here (the variables needed by our program)

segment data use32 class=data
    a db 0
    b db 32
    

; our code starts here
segment code use32 class=code
    start:       
        mov ah, a+b
        ; exit(0)
        push    dword 0      ; push the parameter for exit onto the stack
        call    [exit]       ; call exit to terminate the program
```

Also, I'm using an asm plugin, and this is the code for it:

```
; use the following placeholders:
;     %n - notepad++ dir
;     %s - source name (without path or extension)
;     %d - source dir
[Build]
; the path for the build result
target="%d\%s.exe"
; the build command line
command="cmd /Q /c ""%n\..\nasm\nasm.exe" -fobj "%d\%s.asm" -l "%d\%s.lst" -I"%n\..\nasm\\" && "%n\..\nasm\ALINK.EXE" -oPE -subsys console -entry start "%d\%s.obj""
; the files to remove after the build
filesToRemove="%d\%s.obj"

[Run]
; the command to run
command="cmd /Q /c ""%d\%s.exe" & echo. & pause""
; if a target is specified, it will be checked to have a later date than the source
target="%d\%s.exe"

[Debug]
; the command for debug
command="cmd /Q /c ""%n\..\ollydbg\ollydbg.exe" "%d\%s.exe"""
; if a target is specified, it will be checked to have a later date than the source
target="%d\%s.exe"

[Build custom]
; the path for the build result
target="%d\%s.exe"
; the build command line
command="cmd /Q /c ""%n\..\nasm\nasm.exe" -fobj "%d\%s.asm" -l "%d\%s.lst" -I"%n\..\nasm\\" && "%n\..\nasm\ALINK.EXE" -oPE -subsys console -entry start "%d\%s.obj""
; the files to remove after the build
filesToRemove="%d\%s.obj"

[Run custom]
; the command to run
command="cmd /Q /c ""%d\%s.exe" & echo. & pause""
; if a target is specified, it will be checked to have a later date than the source
target="%d\%s.exe"
```

As I said in one of the comments, the debugger says `AH = 01h` but I'm not quite sure why.

I can provide anything else if you need, I just don't understand why 2 addresses added together in ah works!

Comment: Did you check what the result is? It might surprise you...

Comment: it puts ```01``` in AH, what does that do? why is that? how does that work?

Comment: Please add a complete example, including the NASM command you use for assembling.

Comment: `a` and `b` refer to near addresses of a and b in the data segment (0 and 1 respectively). NASM is smart enough to recognize that as compile time constants and add them together. Now, [a] + [b] would be adding values, and that would be impossible.

Comment: There are no pointers in assembler language. `a` and `b` are addresses. Address is just an integer number.

Comment: I'm surprised that assembles in anything other than a flat binary (`nasm -f bin`).  In a flat binary, label addresses are known at *assemble* time, not just at link time to be filled in according to relocation entries in a `.o`.  But surprisingly NASM doesn't complain about this with `nasm -felf32`, just using the offset-within-section as the "address" to add.  With those 3 lines in that order in a file by themselves, we get `mov ah, 5`.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y51fT1hvn .  YASM says `error: immediate expression too complex` as expected, even with `-f bin`

Comment: I added some examples in the initial question, I just don't get why the addition works! Because, for example ```mov ah, a - $``` gives a syntax error, while the code I've given works and does not provide any errors.

Comment: `mov ah, a-$` works for me with `nasm -f elf64`, with that and the `a:` and `b:` lines as the only lines of the file (so they're in the same section).  `a-$` is distance between two locations in the same section, so that's an assemble-time constant.  But I guess your other example tried that with `a` and `$` in different sections, perhaps hoping to get the distance between sections?  It actually assembles for me (`nasm -fwin32` or `elf32`) with `mov ah, a-$` in `section .text` and `a:` in `section .data`, but with a relocation entry that prob. won't link since you picked an 8-bit destination.

Comment: @PeterCordes The NASM `-f bin` format is actually a linker internal to NASM. So the assembler doesn't actually know numeric values for symbols that are to be relocated. Still, `a + b` works in NASM `-f bin` too.

Comment: @ecm: Yeah, that's what I thought.  But at least it might not be burdened by limited relocation types, but in practice it still doesn't allow `a & 7` so I guess it doesn't have arbitrary linker relocations.  But anyway, `a+b` doesn't get a relocation, it just assembles to an immediate so that's odd.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, the `-f bin` listing file doesn't use [] or () around the byte written for the instruction immediate. And yes, the relocations are not arbitrary, which is why I often work with deltas (subtract one label from another). Negative relocations are another bit that's not supported: https://sourceforge.net/p/nasm/feature-requests/176/